# Chrome Render Bug while resizing Table, header background stick on top of another div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, skia

I have two different panels those are resizable by dragging.
All things are working fine in other browsers but in chrome somehow the **background of header stick to the parent div**. it seems the new rendering problem of `Chrome` with `skia graphics`.

Please have a look on screenshot or [video link](https://youtu.be/mTExyP0FSco) i attached, you will find that glitch on video,help me out to finding the workaround for this.[image: Overlapping background]

And, I tried to compress this problem by applying `background-color` to `table`,`tbody`and wrapper `div` but still sometimes it behaves the same.

If this is not the right place to put this question please suggest me where? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `will-change` property?

Comment: Without the associated HTML/CSS/JS (especially the associated CSS and JS), it's going to be very difficult to identify the problem. I know Skia's use in Chrome has been a popular topic to grumble about (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11367304), but IMO that likely is not your problem here. Are you using a JS framework (like Angular.js) and/or a grid plugin (like ui-grid)? I notice some inline styles in your screenshot that appear to have dynamic references of some sort...there really are too many outstanding questions for me to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @JustJen we are using meteorJs , so blaze for template rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the fact that the glitch occurs outside the table. I would try `overflow: hidden`on the table wrapper.

Comment: i tried that overflow:hidden,but it doesn't work. Do you have some other approach ?

Comment: I need an environement who reproduce the bug to work on it. If you could do it, it's great !